# Multiple Explode

Tags: php, explode

I have a column from excel with the following sample text coming in, and I want to explode it in delimiter. Here is the sample

```
'ABC 11.0x17 / 1x4 / 2x4 XYZ'
'ABC 12.1x18 / 2x4 3x4 XYZ'
'ABC DEF 12.1x19 / 3x4 4x4 XYZ'
'ABC DEF GHI A1 13x20 / 3x4 / 4x4 XYZ'
```

and I need it to be exploded with x and I need only number that is after 1st x which would be 17, 18, 19 or 20 from the above.   I did like the following:

```
$text   = explode('x', $row[6]);
echo $text[1];
```

It gives me 17 / 1, 18 / 2 and so on but I just need 17 or 18 in this case

If anybody have a good solution please write here.

Comment: So you managed to explode something at `x`, but the idea of exploding those results you got again at the `/` does not cross your mind …?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`preg_match`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match) to extract the digits after the first `x`:

```
$strings = array(
    'ABC 11.0x17 / 1x4 2x4 XYZ',
    'ABC 12.1x18 / 2x4 3x4 XYZ',
    'ABC DEF 12.1x19 / 3x4 4x4 XYZ',
    'ABC DEF GHI A1 13x20 / 3x4 4x4 XYZ'
);

foreach ($strings as $str) {
    preg_match('/^[^x]+x(\d+)/', $str, $matches);
    echo $matches[1] . "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
17
18
19
20
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/o8XaV)

If you want to use only [`explode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php), just explode on space after exploding on `x` and take the first value:

```
foreach ($strings as $str) {
    $text = explode('x', $str, 2);
    $text = explode(' ', $text[1]);
    echo "$text[0]\n";
}
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/EVcWm)